# Dict as kwargs whit more variables than used

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, keyword-argument

I have a dictionary with several keys and their respective values.

I want the keys to work as variables and their values as the value of each variable to use them in a function.

I understand that this allows me to have a function with any number of arguments:

```
def myFunc(**kwargs):
    ...
```

And that this allows me to use the keys in the dictionairy as arguments:

```
myDict={
   "foo1":"bar1",
   "foo2":"bar2",
   "foo3":"bar3"}

def myFunc(foo1, foo2):
   ...

myFunc(**myDict)
```

My problem is I have 3 functions that take equal arguments but they also have arguments of their own.

How can I use my dictionary as an argument for all my 3 functions provided that that dictionary has some keys that won't be used in each function.

Something like this:

```
myDict={
   "foo1":"bar1",
   "foo2":"bar2",
   "foo3":"bar3",
   "foo4":"bar4",
   "foo5":"bar5"}

def fun1(**kwargs):
    #takes foo1, foo2 and foo5 as args
def fun2(**kwargs):
    #takes foo1, foo2 and foo4 as args
def fun3(**kwargs):
    #takes foo1, foo2 and foo3 as args

fun1(**myDict)
fun2(**myDict)
fun3(**myDict)
```

How can it be done?

Comment: Well why not *exactly* like that? What is wrong with that code?

Comment: It didn't work. But I had some odd experiences with python lately. Maybe there is something wrong with my installation. I will reinstall and try again.

Comment: Use `dict` comprehension as `**{k:v for k, v in d.items() if k in {'foo1', 'foo2'}}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have two ways to solve this issue. First, as what you have done:

```
def fun1(**kwargs):
    #takes foo1, foo2 and foo5 as args
    foo1 = kwargs.get("foo1")
    foo2 = kwargs.get("foo2")
    foo5 = kwargs.get("foo5")
    # do something with foo1, foo2, foo5
```

You define a function with `kwargs` and pick up *only* what you need inside the function and ignore all else.

The other way is to define exactly what you need in the function signature *plus* a dummy `kwargs`:

```
def fun1(foo1=None, foo2=None, foo5=None, **kwargs):
    #takes foo1, foo2 and foo5 as args
    # do something with foo1, foo2, foo5
```

In both way, you can call the function with `fun1(**myDict)`. Only the latter will trigger warning from a static analyser that you have unused variable `kwargs`, which is intentional.

Answer (score 2):

> How can it be done?

This is bad API. Don't do it. Functions should be explicit about the inputs, unless there is a really good reason to accept `**kwargs` (e.g. you have to pass them on to somewhere else, and you don't know in advance what are the possible keywords here).

> How can I use my dictionary as an argument for all my 3 functions provided that that dictionary has some keys that won't be used in each function.

Instead of having a dictionary that is the union of all arguments (foo1-foo5), use a dictionary that has the intersection of all arguments (foo1, foo2).  Pass in the other arguments separately:

```
fun1(foo5=x, **common)
fun3(foo3=y, **common)
```

Comment: The dictionary is something that is provided and I cannot change

Comment: Then just get out the vars you need, you don't have to change the dictionary here.